# How to make $.load() execute scripts that get returned in HTML via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am making an AJAX call and get back a partialView.
In this partialView I have script that I want to execute.
After searching on the Internet I found that I need to use "eval" in order to make this work. After this I found that the $.load() method does this for me.

However it is not working for me.

My code:

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="headerContainer">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 itemContainerHeader">
        <h4> Namn</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 itemContainerHeader">
        <h4> Epost</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 itemContainerHeader">
        <h4> Nummer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var c in Model.Customers)
{
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 containerListItem">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            @(c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            @c.Email
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            @c.PhoenNumber
        </div> 
    </div> 
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $.scissors.customers.init();
    </script>
}
```

The init method do not get executed when loading the page with AJAX:

```
  getView: function (url, callback, options) {
    var settings = {
        target: "#contentContainer"
    }

    $.extend(settings, options);

    $.LoadingOverlay("show");

    $(settings.target).empty().load(url, function (data) {

        if (callback)
            callback();
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    });
}
```

jQuery documentation for $.load():

> Script Execution
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> 1 $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you need to load a library before the script.

Comment: it is loaded in the layout page and is constantly there after I logg in

Comment: Sections are not rendered when returning a PartialViewResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I figured this out.

The problem was the razor syntax here:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $.scissors.customers.init();
    </script>
}
```

I made an AJAX call and returned a partialView and when the new HTML gets appended to the DOM the browser did not know how to read the razor syntax.

I simply removed the razor syntax like this and it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.scissors.customers.init();
</script>
```

However I want to point out that this was/is not a best practice soloution.
I have a function getView that also accepts a callback parameter and it is better practice to call the init function in the callback like so:

```
     $.scissors.worker.getView("/Customer/GetCustomer", function () {
            $.scissors.customers.customerCard.edit.init();
        }, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

This script:

```
$.scissors.customers.init();
```

only gets executed if the main view has loaded the library globally. i.e. the library at head section of the page:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='scissors.js'></script>
```

if `scissors.js` is available in the global scope then your script will get executed when you `.load()`.

Comment: To clarify: My scripts are loaded in the masterpage and are accesable but for some reason the load() function does not seem to include the scripts